# Delete the [dhtml] tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, burninate-request

On StackOverflow, we have a [dhtml](/questions/tagged/dhtml) tag, which is quite useless. DHTML is *"is an umbrella term for a collection of technologies used together to create interactive and animated web sites by using a combination of HTML, JS and CSS"*.

It's just a collection name for HTML + JS/CSS. That means every question tagged with [dhtml](/questions/tagged/dhtml) has also a [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag and one/both of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and [css](/questions/tagged/css), which means the tag doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that we can just delete this. There are 127 [questions tagged DHTML without 'CSS', 'HTML', or 'JavaScript'](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103561/dhtml-questions-not-tagged-html-javascript-or-css), and it may be detrimental to just delete the tag altogether.

Comment: There are also [8 questions tagged just 'DHTML'](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/103562) as of march 11th that would need to be cleaned up as well.

Comment: Personally I'd alias it to html

Comment: Aliasing to [html] sound like the best way to go, but I want to hear a few other opinions or see some more votes first.

Answer (score 5):

I would agree with aliasing [dhtml](/questions/tagged/dhtml) to [html](/questions/tagged/html) because

1. By the defininition of DHTML (i.e. dynamic HTML), every DHTML question is also an HTML question
2. The questions that are also related to CSS and/or JavaScript should already be tagged as such.

Comment: how about we just commit the term to history and move on. It would be more fitting to talk about StaticHTML nowerdays to talk about non-dynamic web pages.